# H1 not functioning after adding navbar & background-color to CSS

Tags: html, css, text, header

- My code not working I tried to add text to my code after adding my
  navbar in background-color in Css.

  <!doctype html>

  Home Page

  < !----Toggle--->

  < !----Icon Widgets--->

  ```
           <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
               <li class="nav-item>
             <<form>
               <label for="search class="search bar></label>
               </form>
               <a class="nav-link" href=""><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></a>
               <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></a>
               </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
  ```

Comment: Quick question @Ihyaulhaq Maulana if I'm trying to add my h1 under my navigation bar how would I do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
You got an extra < on <<form>
So by remove this maybe will help you

 <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
         <li class="nav-item>
       <form>
         <label for="search class="search bar></label>
         </form>
         <a class="nav-link" href=""><input type="text" placeholder="Search"></a>
         <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href=""><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i></a>
         </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to check all your code if any wrong type.
like `<<form>` on your code

Comment: Okay, let me check my code real fast and thank you.